# Kivy, Calling a function after the __init__ one

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I recently started working with Kivy and I'm stuck with this problem. I want to create in the Python code a set of Labels and give them a position, the problem is that the `__init__()` function is called when the size of the Kivy window isn't updated and so all my Labels are placed in the left-bottom corner of the window and they are way to small, because by default the window size is 100x100.
How can I solve this? I thought of just putting the code which generate these Labels into a function that is called after the `__init__()` one, when the window size are updated. How can I do this?

You will find my code below:

```
class LabelsWindow(BoxLayout):
    labels_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(**kwargs)

         label_height = dp(50)
         i = 0
         for e in self.labels_list:
             label = Label(text=e, size_hint=(1, label_height), pos_hint={'x':0, 'top':1-(label_height/self.height)*i})
             self.add_widget
             i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Never worked with Kivy before, but if I have time later I'll try to reproduce your example and provide a more concrete solution. In the meantime, humor me and add:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
     super(LabelsWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Also, change this:

```
self.add_widget(label)
```

or alternatively:

```
self.add_widget(Label(text=e, size_hint=(1, label_height), pos_hint={'x':0, 'top':1-(label_height/self.height)*i}))
```

Answer (score 0):

try to uncomment but it will not work that all i have

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App

class LabelsWindow(App):
    def build(self):
        b=BoxLayout()
        labels_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
        label_height = 50
        i = 0
        for e in labels_list:
            l=b.add_widget(Label(text=e, size_hint=(1, None),height=label_height))#,pos_hint={'x':0, 'top':1-(label_height/self.height)*i})
            #l.bind(pos_hint={'x':0, 'top':1-(label_height/l.setter('height'))*i})
            i += 1
        return b

LabelsWindow().run()
```